# Edit with NotePad++ right-click explorer shortcut not showing

Tags: troubleshooting, shell, windows-explorer, shortcuts

When I first installed NotePad++ it created a short cut (shell extension) to allow your to right click on a file and choose "Edit with NotePad++".

It actually was there and I installed the "e" trial and my "Edit with Notepad++" shortcut went away. I have since uninstalled E.

I have also uninstalled/reinstalled NP++ but that still didn't bring the shell integration back.

I also found a blog entry where someone said the the SCiTE editor messes this up to. But, I don't have scite installed.... at least it isn't on my add/remove list.

Can anyone tell me why this might not be working any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the NotePad++ version 5.6.4 today and the right-click shortcut is now there. I'm going to assume this was an installer error on the version I was installing before.

Comment: In my case the shell integration doesn't show up with web shortcuts (saved in File Explorer)...

Comment: That's probably because the file type of a web shortcut isn't registered to be edited with notepad++. You can probably right click open-with, select NP++ and tell it always and that would register that file type with NP++

Comment: Yeah... it should work that way but it doesn't show the "Open with" either (it does in any other file type...)

Comment: What is the file type of the firefox web shortcut?

Comment: Both Chrome and FIrefox shortcuts are .url files...